# Approximation of function with neural networks

Tags: neural-network

I am looking for the relevant techniques to approximate a function on $[0,1]$ with a neural network when the function has a huge amplitude?

Here is an example with a simple neural network. For test = 1 everything works well. For test = 2 then the algo "converges" towards a constant. Why?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

sample_size = 5000000

test = 1

if test == 1:
    learning_rate = 1e-2
    alpha = 2.
elif test == 2:
    learning_rate = 5e-10
    alpha = 2000000.

xs = np.random.normal(0.,1.,sample_size).reshape(-1,1)
ys = alpha * xs * xs

xs_test = np.arange(-3.,3.,0.01).reshape(-1,1)
ys_test = alpha * xs_test * xs_test

matplotlib.interactive(True)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.plot(xs_test, ys_test, 'r')
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.flush_events()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,1))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,1))

batch_size = 50
nb_batches = int(np.ceil(sample_size/batch_size))

with tf.name_scope('nn'):
    hidden = tf.layers.dense(x, 50, name="hidden", activation=tf.nn.elu)
    outcome = tf.layers.dense(hidden, 1, name="output")    
with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outcome - y))    
with tf.name_scope('train'):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(nb_batches):
        indices = slice(i*batch_size, (i+1)*batch_size)
        mini_batch_x = xs[indices]
        mini_batch_y = ys[indices]
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print('loop: ', i, 'loss:', loss.eval(feed_dict = {x: xs_test, y: ys_test}))
            ax.clear()
            ax.plot(xs_test, ys_test, 'r')
            ax.plot(xs_test, outcome.eval(feed_dict = {x: xs_test}), 'b.')
            fig.canvas.draw()
            fig.canvas.flush_events()
        sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={x: mini_batch_x, y: mini_batch_y})
```

Comment: What is the goal here? Fast approximation algorithm?

Comment: Theoretically with a neural network you can approximate any functions!! You better give some actual examples, piece of code, at the moment it is quite vague what you want and what I answered should be sufficient.

Comment: Why is it still on hold?

Answer (score 1):

Neural networks are function approximators, thus the answer is yes. Neural networks go from a set of inputs and map them to a set of outputs. That is precisely what a function does as well. In theory a sufficiently deep enough network and sufficient data coverage can approximate any function within a finite range.

---

Let's look at an example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

We will approximate some arbitrary function

$y = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_1x_2^2 + \text{tan}(x_1)$

```
def func(x1, x2):
    return x1**2 + x2**2 + x1*x2**2 + np.tan(x1)
```

We will bound our inputs from $[-1, 1]$.

```
n = 10000
x_train =  (np.random.rand(n,2) - 0.5) * 2
y_train = np.zeros((n,))

for i in range(n):
    y_train[i] = func(x_train[i,0], x_train[i,1])

n = 1000
x_test =  (np.random.rand(n,2) - 0.5) * 2
y_test = np.zeros((n,))

for i in range(n):
    y_test[i] = func(x_test[i,0], x_test[i,1])

plt.scatter(x_train[:,0], x_train[:,1], c=y_train)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Let's now build a model.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Reshape
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras import backend as K
from keras import optimizers

input_shape = (2,)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='linear',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

sgd = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['mae'])
```

We will train the model

```
epochs = 50
batch_size = 128
# Fit the model weights.
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Let's see how well we did. We will compare the test set that we have to the predicted values.

```
plt.scatter(x_test[:,0], x_test[:,1], c=y_test)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
plt.scatter(x_test[:,0], x_test[:,1], 
            c=model.predict(x_test).reshape(x_test.shape[0],))
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

### Other functions

```
def func(x1, x2):
    if x1 >= 0 and x2 >= 0:
        return x1**2 + x2**2
    else:
        return x1*2 + x2*2
```

Test set

[image]

Prediction

[image]

```
def func(x1, x2):
    return np.sinc(x1 + x2)
```

Test set

[image]

Prediction

[image]

Try your own function with this network.